# Intent filter works from Google+, but not Chrome & Facebook

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml file for [my app on Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enigmadream.picturecode):

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.enigmadream.picturecode.Viewer"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_viewer"
        android:parentActivityName="com.enigmadream.picturecode.Editor" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.enigmadream.picturecode.Editor" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="picturecode.enigmadream.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I thought it was working just fine. It still seems to work just fine if you click on a [link from Google+](https://plus.google.com/116407530080746315185/posts/Fe8rqGAsLBT) - it offers the option to launch my app instead of the browser when you click on a link that uses the server name `picturecode.enigmadream.com`. But when I click on a [link to picturecode.enigmadream.com](http://picturecode.enigmadream.com/?01sv23v6O%C2%A3X2UOaz2tk1C4321UVWVU123g3COOa%40%400i01l6) from within Facebook or Chrome, it doesn't offer the option, and instead just navigates to the page in Chrome. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your own scheme (eg. picturecode://).  Facebook and Chrome can both probably deal with the http scheme on their own and so don't check to see if any other activities can handle it.  The upshot of this is that you may not need to have the host in place either, for a shorter URI.  Just `picturecode://01sv...`.  You can of course also keep this filter in place as well.  If a browser gets to the page, just have a link that goes to the correct URI, or even just automatically redirect if possible.

For reference, you can see Google Play work this way using the market:// scheme.

Comment: How does a page avoid redirecting to a scheme not supported by the current device? For example, what if I have a link to http://picturecode.enigmadream.com/?0110 and the content at picturecode.enigmadream.com redirects to picturecode://0110 but you're viewing the page on a desktop where the picturecode scheme is not supported. Will there be an error; will it simply stay on the last page whose scheme was understood?

Comment: Also, I find it odd that the standard browser on my phone *does* offer to launch PictureCode when I click on an http link that goes to picturecode.enigmadream.com, but when I click on the same link from Chrome on my tablet, it *doesn't* offer to launch an external app. This led me to report a bug at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/KsdGQPPHi7o which seems to be getting some attention. So I'm thinking that I *can* make it work with an alternate scheme, but it *should* also work as-is.

Comment: I finally implemented this solution and it seems to work nicely. I have an .shtml file at the target address that has this in the <head>: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=picturecode:<!--#echo var="QUERY_STRING"-->"/>. And then when I browse with Android it jumps immediately to the app, but if I browse with my desktop, it just stays on the info page at the target address, as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately when I browse to the address from a mobile browser, it doesn't just stay on the page if it doesn't understand the protocol in the redirect. It jumps to an error page. :( ... So I'm asking a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670029/html-redirect-to-custom-protocol-only-when-supporting-android-app-is-installed

Comment: Chrome for Android has been fixed.