# HTML redirect to custom protocol only when supporting Android app is installed

Tags: android, html, redirect, android-intent, intentfilter

I would like to have all URIs intended for my app launch my app if it is installed. And if it is not installed I would like to display a web page about my app. After looking at the following two questions, I still can't find a reliable solution.

[Intent filter works from Google+, but not Chrome & Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191219/intent-filter-works-from-google-but-not-chrome-facebook)

[Android - redirect to store if app not installed (launch from website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518453/android-redirect-to-store-if-app-not-installed-launch-from-website)

The problem with the first solution (redirect) is that redirecting to a custom protocol leads to an error page when the app is not installed, as described in the second question. The problem with the second solution (use http protocol with intent filter by server name) is that Chrome doesn't honor the intent filter, as described in the first question. So now the question is, is there any way to prevent the redirect from occurring when no supported app is installed?

Answer (score -1):

This guy seems to have a solution to your problem:[Android Browser Facebook Redirect Does Not Always Trigger Intent for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036793/android-browser-facebook-redirect-does-not-always-trigger-intent-for-url).
Or at least it is working quite well. Best thing I have found so far.